# Why does PyQt menu get frozen on macOS?

Tags: macos, qt, menu, pyqt

I wrote a minimal PyQt 5.15 app on macOS Catalina. It just has one menu with one item. While I can see the menu, clicking on it does not open it. It's completely unresponsive. In fact, not even the macOS (apple icon) opens when my app is in focus. If I unfocus and then re-focus on the app, the menu works. I ran the same program on Windows 10 and there was no such problem.

What is causing the menu bar not to work properly in macOS?

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()

        insert_action = QAction("&Open", self)
        insert_action.triggered.connect(self.open_file)

        menu = self.menuBar()

        file_menu = menu.addMenu("&File")
        file_menu.addAction(insert_action)

    def open_file(self):
        pass


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but a workaround:

`menu.setNativeMenuBar(False)`

uses an on-window, non-native macOS menu, similar to those on Windows and Linux, which works.

There are also [online discussions](https://github.com/chewing/chewing-editor/issues/127) mentioning that making the app a bundle solves the issue, but I have not tried that.